# Invalid locale error with facebook likebox widget

Tags: wordpress, facebook, locale, facebook-likebox

This was working fine for some time on my wordpress site but for some days i have been seeing the following where my facebook likebox is supposed to be:
[image: Locale error]

I have cross checked the APP ID and everything. They match. Also, here is what facebook settings looks like:
[image: Facebook app settings]

When I inspect element for the "invalid locale supplied for locale" error , here is what i see in the element box:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?    id=7686354665xxxxx&amp;locale=en&amp;stream=false&amp;header=true&amp;height=290&amp;width=310&amp;connections=10" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:310px; height:290px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Please note that I have changed the ID to xxxx. Interesting thing here is that the likebox appears when I change the "**locale=en**" present in the code above to "**locale=en_US**" on my chrome browser. But i am having a very hard time locating this specific line of code in my file.

Has anyone struggled through this? I checked the default site locale, its en_US.

Answer (score 0):

The Like box is now deprecated. Please use the Page Plugin from now on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages